# Regex matching all integers apart from zero

Tags: java, regex

I would like to express all integers apart from zero with a fixed number of digits. Until now, I have been using `(\\d{3})`.  It works fine, except that it does not exclude `000`.

How do I write this using a regex?

Comment: Use negative lookahead `(?!)`. See regex demo: [`^(?!0{3})\d{3}$`](https://regex101.com/r/xl78pA/3)

Comment: There is a saying in English that goes: ["if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_all_you_have_is_a_hammer,_everything_looks_like_a_nail). You need a new tool.

Comment: `(\d{3})` is match all three-digits pattern...

Answer (score 1):

```
String input = ...
if (input.matches("\\d{3}") && !input.equals("000")) {
   ... // input is a three digit number that's not 000
}
```

Don't underestimate the power of brute force.

Comment: That's pretty much the solution that i have found until now. But i wanted to use regular expresions to save some lines of code. Anyway thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Try this RegEx:

> `((?!000)(\\d{3}))`

It will match every 3 numbers not being equal to `000`.

Comment: Ummm, but he wants to match `001`, it would seem.

Comment: If that's the case, he can use `((?!000)(\d{3}))` instead to bring every three numbers not being equal to `000` @torazaburo

Comment: I tried both of the above, they didn't really work and i think i didn't make any mistakes. Nevertheless thank you for your support.

Comment: I was doing something wrong, this ((?!000)(\\d{3})) worked perfectly for my case. I thank you very much.

Comment: Nice to know. I'll edit the answer to mark the question as solved. Cheers.